# Connecting to lan network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, lan, multiplayer

I am writing a platform game, and i thought it would be cool to add a multi-player mode for people who are playing on the same network.  My question is how would i query through all the available computers open on a certain port for connecting to play multi-player, and then how would i establish a connection with them.  I thought i could just create a socket and just try to connect on every port, but how would i do that if i dont know the other computer ip address.  On google i saw this question get asked several times, however none of the answers actually seemed helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will propably want to broadcast a message (broadcasts are received by all devices on the network). Then you would have the other machines listening fir such incoming broadcasts.

Basically in a broadcast you would advertise that a computer is running the program, and is willing to establish a direct connection. Then one of the computers would connect straight to the other, and you would work on from there.

EDIT: [Someones similarily done aproach in java (blog post)](http://blog.javamonday.com/2012/05/using-java-udp-broadcast-to-detect.html)

Comment: but how would i know from the server when the client was trying to connect

Comment: You would have the server broadcast its existence, and in the broadcast it could tell what port it is listening to. Then all the clients would connect to the advertised port. I haven't really looked into network programming, but the server should be able to see an incoming connection?